# Java Linked HashMap with ArrayList empty checking

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

How to check wheather specific kay have an empty value in a LinkedhashMap

```
Map<String,List<String>>resultTable = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

following are the resultTable

Key = `Sr.ID` and values are `{660316, 660320, 590089, 661725, 661865, 661864, 661862, 660300}`
Key = `Docket` and values are `{0150, 0150b1, 142747, 1725.186589, 2708.5, 2738.56, 45rdfg, 56t}`
Key = `Rec No` and values are`{,8821893, , , , , , , }`

how can we check if particular key (i.e Sr.ID or Docket or Rec No.)have an empty Value in the List (Rec No, Key have an Empty Value)

how can we check if particular key (i.e Sr.ID or Docket or Rec No.)don't have an empty Value in the List
Docket Key Don't have an empty Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple method for checking an empty value for a particular key:

```
private boolean checkEmptyVal(String key){

        boolean result = false;
        List<String> val = resultTable.get(key);

        if(val != null && val.contains("")) {
            result = true;              
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `get` method from hashmap does requires an Object as an input. And here it is being passed as String.

Comment: Check user's map declaration: `Map<String,List<String>>resultTable`

Answer (score 3):

Your values are of type `List<String>`.

To check that an element of the list is empty for any given key, you can simply:

```
// iterate map entries
for (String key: resultTable.keySet()) {
    // TODO null check!
    if (resultTable.get(key).contains("")) {
        // list has an empty element
        System.out.printf("Found an empty value for %s%n", key);
    }
}
```

**Note**

And here's a Java 8 syntax with a `BiConsumer<String,List<String>>` lambda:

```
resultTable.forEach(
    (s,l) -> {
        // TODO null check!
        if (l.contains("")) System.out.printf("Found an empty value for %s%n", s);
    }
);
```

Comment: @Nizil nope. OP is checking whether their list **contains** an empty value. It doesn't make any sense to compare an empty `String` with a `List`.

Comment: @Nizil This is `List.contains(Object)`, not `String.contains(String)`

Comment: @Mena @Chop Thought `value` was the element of the list... I shouldn't say anything before my coffee

Comment: @Nizil which reminds me... Coffee time for me too! Have a good one :)

Comment: This code is missing what `key` is actually having a empty value.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, an empty value is not a `null` but an empty string.

To check for an empty value in a list, you can do `list.contains("")`.

Translated to your context, this is:

```
if (resultTable.get(key).contains("")) {
    // empty value here
}
```

[Mena suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32266958/1734119) checking for all keys one after the other:

```
// iterate map values
for (List<String> value: resultTable.values()) {
    if (value.contains("")) {
        // list has an empty element
    }
}
```

You can also add code to remove all empty values from a list:

```
while (list.remove("")) {
    log.debug("Empty value removed");
}
```